# How to sample from a distribution while the sample point simultaneously needs to satisfy an inequality constraint?

Tags: probability, dirichlet-distribution, distributions, importance-sampling, constraint

I have a Dirichlet distribution $P(x)$ , where $x$ is a point on a simplex. It is very easy to sample from this Dirichlet distribution. But I have a set of non-linear, non-convex constraints

$f_i(x)>=0, i=1,2...N$.

How do I sample a point from this distribution such that it satisfies the constraints?

I tried it this way so far, I first sample a point from $P$, then I use a few iterations of gradient ascent on the point $x$ using the sum of the gradient of the constraint function $f_i(x)$, and it got me to a point that satisfies the constraints but the point turns out to be in the low probability region of P.

So how do I combine the gradient of $f_i$ as well as gradient of P, to move to a point which satisfies the constraints but also in reasonably high probability region of P.

What method should I use and how, what I am basically trying to do is approximate the distribution over $x$ that satisfies the constraints but has the proportional probability value of $P(x)$ otherwise.

So I tried using importance sampling as follows:
1. Sample a set of points from $P(x)$
2. Do a few iterations of gradient ascent on points that do not satisfy these constraints, $x=x+\sum \alpha\nabla f_i(x), i=1,2,...,N $
till it satisfies the constraints.

The problem is, the points thus moved goes to the low probability region of $P(x)$ and my importance sampler is not representative of the true distribution.

Please note that 'P' is convex.
Please suggest a way around the problem.

Comment: Can you give an explicit example for the $f_i(x)$?  If efficiency is not an issue then how about rejection sampling?

Comment: No its not possible, sometimes the inequality space would be too small over the simplex, so we need to somehow use the gradient information. I am afraid $fi(x)$ is a little complex to explain and it is domain specific. But it is a twice differentiable non-convex function. Infact, it has no closed form expression but the gradient can be evaluated at any given point.

Comment: OK.  Not my area but hopefully someone else has a good suggestion!  BTW you can write f_i to get $f_i$ (and I changed it in your question).  Also, what you describe doesn't really seem to be importance sampling (which is a kind of change of measure approach)?

Comment: No problem, Thanks for replying. But I don't  "understand change of measure approach". Am just describing plain old IS as a way to approximate a distribution. But with the twist of gradient ascent which btw seems to have no mention in the literature. I am sure this method is disguised by another name. Would you recommend posting in someother math websites?

Comment: I don't know any more suitable website.  My point about importance sampling is that it seems to be missing in your question- is that by accident?